# What are the typical tasks of a Design Verification Engineer?

Tags: verification

I'm quite confused on what should be the typical tasks of a Design Verification Engineer in ASIC Design. In my experience these were the things that I do:

- Create verification plan
- Create testbench architecture plan
- Build the testbench
- Create the testcases
- Run RTL regression to verify the DUT until coverage is 100%
- Run GLS

Now, I don't know if the following are still the responsibility of the Design Verification Engineer:

- Debug the RTL (Is this a task of the RTL Design Engineer?)
- Linting (Is this a task of the RTL Design Engineer?)
- LEC (Is this a task of the RTL Design Engineer?)
- Synthesis (Is this a task of the RTL Design Engineer?)
- STA (Is this a task of the PNR Engineer?)
- Debug timing (Task of RTL Design Engineer or PNR Engineer?)
- Generate SDF (Task of RTL Design Engineer or PNR Engineer?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your first guesses seem right.  You would create and run testcases to verify functionality of the RTL.

For the other items, I have listed how I would classify them.

It will definitely vary between companies.  But in general I would say:

- Debug the RTL (RTL Design Engineer; Circuit Design Engineer if you want to try different implementation than how it was originally coded)
- Linting (RTL Design Engineer, sometimes they pass off bad RTL, then it becomes Design Engineer's job)
- LEC (Library Design Engineer on individual cells; RTL vs. Schematic is Circuit Design Engineer, RTL vs. RTL may be RTL Design Engineer)  There are other equivalence tools as well such as symbolic which could be used.
- Synthesis (Circuit Design Engineer on critical blocks; Physical Design Engineer at top level glue logic)
- STA (Circuit Design Engineer on critical blocks; Physical Design Engineer at top level)
- Debug timing (Library Design Engineer on individual cells; Circuit Design Engineer on critical blocks; Physical Design Engineer at top level)
- Generate SDF (Library Design Engineer on individual cells; Circuit Design Engineer on critical blocks; Physical Design Engineer at top level)

Depending on how wild-west your company is you could do all of these!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, it looks like the task differs from company to company. Or sometimes from project to project.

Anyway, the reason why I asked this is because in project management, it's better if there are division of labor to make tasks run in parallel. Although this might take more engineers for a project, it helps in reducing the time of finishing the project.